ProgressView not showing in MenuBarExtra
The issue
I'm having trouble having a linear ProgressView show in a MenuBarExtra, it would simply not appear.
Apparently, there is no counter-indication indicating that it is impossible to do so but I still fail to implement it.
Here is the minimal code structure:
import SwiftUI
import AppKit

@main
struct Menubar_InfoApp: App {
    @State private var pct: String = "34%"

    var body: some Scene {
        MBE()
    }

    @SceneBuilder
    func MBE() -> some Scene {
        MenuBarExtra() {
            VStack {
                Text("Percentage: \(pct)")
                    .padding()
                
                ProgressView(value: Double(pct.dropLast(1)) ?? 0, total: 100)
                    .progressViewStyle(LinearProgressViewStyle())
                    .padding([.leading, .trailing])
                    .frame(width: 100)
            }
            
        } label: {
            Text("sample")
        }
    }
}

Goal
I'm just looking for a way to have a linear ProgressView in a MenuBarExtra (that has the same appearance and behaviour as one at least - the app being composed a multiple MenuBarExtra elements, the intent would be not to have them overlap) similar to:

What I've tried

I don't think the issue is linked with the value itself as I tried setting a hard value (doesn't work).
The issue doesn't seem to be linked with the MenuBarExtra being called through a separate function, not directly in the body, but still, even if I move it there it fails to work.


Try this approach adding .menuBarExtraStyle(.window) to your MenuBarExtra{...}.
Works for me, tested on macOS 15.2, using Xcode 16.2.
 @SceneBuilder
 func MBE() -> some Scene {
     MenuBarExtra() {
         VStack {
             Text("Percentage: \(pct)").padding()
             ProgressView(value: Double(pct.dropLast(1)) ?? 0, total: 100)
                 .progressViewStyle(LinearProgressViewStyle())
                 .padding([.leading, .trailing])
                 .frame(width: 100)
         }
     } label: {
         Text("sample")
     }
     .menuBarExtraStyle(.window) // <-- here
 }


Thanks for the answer. This works indeed but it does not look like a regular MenuBarExtra if you see what I mean. This, quite rationally, behaves as a window, meaning that another MenuBarExtra (of the same app) can be opened at the same time (they overlap - and that's not what I want). Furthermore, this is not a regular window, meaning that if I want to simulate the regular MenuBarExtra experience, I don't think it would be possible to modify the opacity nor the unwanted behaviour described above. I am sorry this was not highlighted in the question. Do you think there is a solution? Thanks.

I can only answer the question you ask. I cannot guess what other code you have or plan to have, I can only see the code you show, and my answer works very well for that.

Yes well, I guess you're right. I should have included more details in the question.
